# No matching constructor for initialisation of 'ifstream'

Tags: c++, file, class, ifstream

I am geting an an error in the following code it worked fine in visual studio but once i have moved it over to Xcode that uses gcc to compile get this error No matching constructor for initialisation of 'ifstream' i have looked at adding this as a reference rather than a copy as suggested on this site but it still came up with the error.

```
void getAndSetTextData::GetBannedList(string fileName)
{
    bannedWordCount = 0;
    ifstream inFile(fileName);
    while(inFile >> currentWord)
    {
        bannedWords.push_back(currentWord);
        bannedWords[bannedWordCount++] = currentWord;
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My argument against explicit use of close: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/544/507 Basically if you don't care if there is an error then let the destructor do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) constructor accepts a `const char*` as the filename (prior C++11):

```
ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str());
```

An additional constructor that accepts a `const std::string&` as the filename was added in C++11.

*Minor point: consider changing argument `string fileName` to `const string& fileName` to avoid unnecessary copy of `fileName`.*

Comment: About time they finally decided to add a constructor that takes a string.  :)

Comment: Is fileName an actual variable defined in your program, or is it a variable the user reading this question is supposed to fill in with the full path?

I ask because in my program I'm using the argv[1] variable to hold the path, and .c_str() does *NOT* work with it

Comment: @MarcusJ, it is an argument in OP's code and is a `std::string`. `argv[1]` is a `char*`.

Comment: of course that's why it won't work! it's not a string! thanks for the help, dude.

Answer (score 1):

first you should check that weather the file is opened or not. for example if you dont have permission to access the file or if you are opening a file in write mode when there is no enough disk space, etc...
so

```
ifstream inFile(fileName);
if( ! inFile )
   return;
while(inFile >> currentWord)
```

and about your question, are you including the fstream?

Comment: Not really nesacery. If the file failed to open correctly then the loop will never be entered anyway.